# How can I put icon markers on Google maps, and is there a quota on number of icons?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps, geospatial

How in Google Maps JavaScript do I say, "I want a marker to be placed at this latitude and longitude, with animation, and with this 30x20 icon [with any needed information for the icon]?"

Is there any limit on how many different icons I can have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this: [Google Maps API - Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

Some really good examples there...

Typically there is an icon for the overlay and also one for the shadow but you may be able to override this behavior...

Edit: Added more content:

There is no default shadow. If you are using custom icons, you need to provide both the icon and the image for the shadow. I have used [Custom Marker Generator](http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php) in the past to generate the shadow image.

Here's some example code from Google. Notice both the image and the shadow are specified...

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

    setMarkers(map, beaches);
}

/**
 * Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for
 * the order in which these markers should display on top of each
 * other.
 */
var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/beachflag.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
      new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/beachflag_shadow.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML <area> element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}
```

Example here: [Complex Icon Example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to specify a custom icon but the default shadow?